# Microservice - Catalog and inventory tracking on different tables

Tags: database-design, schema, microservices, database-schema

I'm currently exploring the microservice architecture and base on what I've read so far it's good to separate the catalog microservice/database to inventory and that's where I want to go.

The problems:

Since the catalog will be on another database (PostgreSQL/MongoDB) compare to the inventory (PostgreSQL). When I want to create a report of inventory movement with product code, what's the best way to model it? So far I'm sending the productId to the inventory but not the code as it might change.

What's the best way to track the inventory movement? I have this schema in mind:

--

```
InventoryTransaction
-productId
-operationDate
-action (IN/OUT)
-count

InventoryTransactionSummary <- updated daily
-productId
-prevTotal - total from the previous date
-total - prevTotal + productIn - productOut
-productIn - in stock
-productOut - sold, pullout, etc
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm currently exploring the microservice architecture and base on what I've read so far it's good to separate the catalog microservice/database to inventory and that's where I want to go.

It is not a golden rule.

The important thing is to first understand the business logic. Do you really need a separate service for each of your use cases ?

I did not fully understand your example, but from my experience, here are some options:

1. Use event sourcing. Save only the necessary data of the event that happened and upon reading it, rebuild the state or use hourly/daily snapshots of the final state, to avoid recomputing state every time. That way, you will have your services, like you defined above, and you will have a service which connects to the event sourcing db and recreates state according to some functionality you defined. Read more [here](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/event-sourcing.html)
2. The databases you use for OLTP - online transaction processing, like Postgres, for example, is not suited for OLAP - online analytical processing. You can save you data the same way you showed in your example, but you can add a trigger to your database, that on every insert, send the event to an OLAP database, which can model your data for better analytical purposes. Read more [here](https://techdifferences.com/difference-between-oltp-and-olap.html)
3. Before jumping to conclusions with separating services, ask yourself, do you really need to separate two services? For example, car and wheels. If I always need the wheels with the car, why separate? It only gives me more headache. Read more [here](https://medium.com/ingeniouslysimple/aggregates-in-domain-driven-design-5aab3ef9901d)